# Syntax Error when Updating Database in Visual Studios

Tags: vba, ms-access

I connected my access database to my web form in Visual Studios but when try update records in the database it comes up with a Syntax Error.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= StudentDatabase.mdb"
        sql = "SELECT * FROM StudentDatabase"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

        da.Fill(ds, "StudentDatabase")

        Label1.Text = ds.Tables("StudentDatabase").Rows(1).Item("Student First Name")

        con.Open()
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        ds.Tables("StudentDatabase").Rows(1).Item("Student First Name") = TextBox1.Text
        da.Update(ds, "StudentDatabase")
    End Sub
End Class
```

It should update the database with what was written in the text box but it comes up with a syntax error.

Comment: If I change that it comes up with this error: System.ArgumentException: 'Column '[Student First Name]' does not belong to table StudentDatabase.'

Comment: What is the name of the column? And what is the original syntax error?

Comment: the name of the column is 'Student First Name'. The original syntax error is: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement.'

Comment: Not showing syntax of UPDATE statement. However, field names with spaces should be enclosed in [ ]. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.